# How can i add a 'preview' button in the edit page of the django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

After long searches, I still didn't find any answers I've been able to apply.

I have in my django app a models which creates new pages in the website:

```
class Page(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    content = HTMLField('Content')
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    background_image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to="page_background/",
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        default="default/livresse_logo.png",
    )
```

As you can see there's a WYSIWYG editor in it, a title and a background image.

When I go to the admin page it's like this:

[image]

I'm looking for a way to add a button 'preview' (maybe next to the save button) that would show the content of my model included in the template that will be use to display the page before saving.
I'd like this button only displaying for that model.
Hope i'm clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is an elegant solution, but you can solve your problem a little differently, implement the Boolean parameter is_published in the model, and write the view in such a way that the articles that are not yet is_published are only seen by the superuser, so I usually organize a preview.

Comment: Actually if it was for me that's what i would do, but it's a special demand, so i make my own admin for the moment, just for this feature, i don't have any other ideas, but it's a lot of work just for this (i begin in django and web dev). A least it works. Question is still open.